# How can I use admin layout in Padrino for my main app?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, padrino

I have controller

```
app/controllers/posts.rb
```

How can I use admin layout from

```
admin/views/layouts/application.haml
```

?

Comment: You better specify the framework you're working with in the question too. I haven't read the tags first and assumed need help with Rails.

Comment: Added "Padrino" to title, thanks

Comment: If Padrino does not use `admin/views/layouts/application.haml` by default, I would try to add a parameter. For example `haml :index, :layout => :admin` (As done in Sinatra)

Comment: I doubt that `haml :index, :layout => :admin` works, because `/admin` in Padrino is an embedded app on its own.